# Single PNG file for multiple icons

Tags: css, web, webpack

I have noticed that Facebook and Instagram uses the same way of displaying icons found on the site, which is to add into a single PNG file all the icons and make the styling based on their position?

Please have a look on the [Instagram way of doing it](https://www.instagram.com/static/bundles/sprite_core_2x.png/2f351c15a81e.png).

I understand that in this way, the client will receive only a single image which will be cached and the user performance will increase. But how do they do it?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: It is called an image sprite. Your DIV will have an overflow of hidden and the background position will be changed around https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They do it by making a div or span or whatever, with a background of that image and then change the background position.

Example

```
.icons {
  height:20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-image: url("path/to/image");
}

.icon1{
  background-position: 0 0
}

.icon2{
  background-position: 30px 0
}
```

**JSFiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/qxjyycv2/

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is Image Sprites.

The div you are displaying the image in (always as a background image) is set to `overflow: hidden;` while the background position changes to display the correct part of the sprite.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use this tool to generate CSS Sprites(one single png image) from your multiple images along with their css:
[CSS SPRITE GENERATOR](https://www.toptal.com/developers/css/sprite-generator/)